# react hooks: useState nested other useState, setState is not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i write example of dynamically adding text with react useHooks.And using useState to nest.
But, there is a problem, the setState is not working?

when i click the text,The setState in the component does not take effect(Normally, it is add a class to the currently clicked text and delete the class on other texts), how do i do?

Below is the specific code link：

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-sky-z0p9w?file=/src/App.js

Thanks!

Comment: Bro, Are you referring to cellList state ?

Comment: React functional components are pretty messed up and all normal Javascript logic, closure state all kind of go out the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your code is that is this:

```
    const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(null);
```

You are defining this at `App` level. And you are expecting this will work in `TableCel` which in another component which has its own state.

Better way would be out your `TableCel` component outside from `App` and use state there. If you need to use inside `App` then pass `activeItems` and `setActiveItem` as a props as well.

Here is code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(null);

  const TableCel = (props) => {
    const { title } = props;

    return <div>{title}</div>;
  };
  const cell = [
    {
      key: 1,
      header: <TableCel id={1} title={"Header"} />,
      render: (cvm) => (
        <>
          <p>--</p>
        </>
      )
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      header: <TableCel id={2} title={"Header"} />,
      render: (cvm) => (
        <>
          <p>--</p>
        </>
      )
    },
    {
      key: 3,
      header: <TableCel id={3} title={"Header"} />,
      render: (cvm) => (
        <>
          <p>--</p>
        </>
      )
    },
    {
      key: 4,
      header: <TableCel id={4} title={"Header"} />,
      render: (cvm) => (
        <>
          <p>--</p>
        </>
      )
    },
    {
      key: 5,
      header: <TableCel id={5} title={"Header"} />,
      render: (cvm) => (
        <>
          <p>--</p>
        </>
      )
    }
  ];
  const [cellList, addCells] = useState(cell);

  const [count, setCount] = useState(6);

  // console.log(cellList);

  const addCell = (value) => {
    const _cell = {
      key: value,
      header: <TableCel title="Header" id={value} />,
      render: (cvm) => (
        <>
          <p>--</p>
        </>
      )
    };
    addCells([...cellList, _cell]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCount(count + 1);
          addCell(count + 1);
        }}
      >
        add li
      </button>
      <div>
        {cellList
          .filter((cell) => cell.key < 60)
          .map((filteredPerson, index) => (
            <li
              key={index}
              onClick={() => {
                setActiveItem(filteredPerson.key);
              }}
              className={filteredPerson.key === activeItem ? "cel-active" : ""}
            >
              {filteredPerson.header}
            </li>
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-cookies-8eud6?file=/src/App.js:0-2086

Comment: Thanks,i want to add a class to the currently clicked text and delete the class on other texts, How do i do?

Comment: I don't think you actually need to move logic in `TableCel`. Keep that for only ui part. Updated my code and sandbox also. Please check again

Comment: Thanks, it is very usdful to me.

Comment: hi Shubham. now I have a scene almost similar to the above, but using existing components.how to use setState to activeItem state had already change.  i want to make a effect click the table head add class and delete the class on other table head. how do i do ,can you help me,Thanks. this is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-haze-scosm?file=/index.tsx

Comment: Hi Janily not working codesandbox link. Can you update it?

Comment: this link is working. https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-haze-scosm?file=/index.tsx:328-2871

Comment: i am sorry,please check this link https://codepen.io/janily/pen/xxObWVZ  is it ok ?

Comment: hi,Shubham,could you see this link, is it ok? https://codepen.io/janily/pen/xxObWVZ

Comment: Hi Janily, Thanks for this pen. I couldn't find which library are you using. I need to check there doc. Can you share that library

Answer (score 1):

The reason it does not work its because you're accessing the value of `activeItem` state inside of a function. accessing state inside of a function is not recommended cause it will always have the initial value even if the state were updated. That's why `<TableCel>` does not re-render since it does not know that activeItem state had already change.

I recommend that you only access the state inside of `useEffect()`, `useCallback()`, `useMemo()` and inside of the `return` statement of your component.

For Example:

```
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState('initial Value')

  function someFunction(){
    // It's not recommended to access the state inside of this function
    // cause the value of the state will always be ('initial Value')
    // even if the state were updated
    console.log(state)
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    // It's good if you access the value of the state here
    // It will be assured it will always have the updated value
    console.log(state)
  },[state]) 

  return (
    // You can also access the value of the state inside return statement        
    <>
    {console.log(state)}
    <SomeComponent props={state}/>
    </>
  )
}
```

Solution:

Pass the state of activeItem by using context hook. In this way <TableCel> will really know everytime activeItem state change.

Take a look in this code in sandbox link were I use context hook to solve the problem

https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-star-zo4ej?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks, it is very useful to me.

Comment: hi Rehan,now I have a scene almost similar to the above, but using existing components.how to use setState to activeItem state had already change. i want to make a effect click the table head add class and delete the class on other table head. how do i do ,can you help me,Thanks. this is my code: https://codepen.io/janily/pen/xxObWVZ